# window is not defined Angular SSR

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm using AGM Maps and I'm loading the map key dynamically from API.

In App Module.ts

```
export function agmConfigFactory(http: HttpClient, config: LazyMapsAPILoaderConfigLiteral) {
  const id = window.location.pathname.replace(/\//g, "");
  return () => http.get<any>(`API`).pipe(
    map(response => {
      config.apiKey = response['mapkey'];
      console.log(response['mapkey']);
      return response;
    })
  ).toPromise();
}

 providers: [
      {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: agmConfigFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient, LAZY_MAPS_API_CONFIG],
        multi: true
      }
    ],
```

Because of the above code, while running the `npm run prerender` I'm getting the below error,

```
ask: Promise.then ; Value: ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.agmConfigFactory [as useFactory]
```

How can I fix it ? Please help

Comment: use isPlatformBrowser

Comment: or use Angular Location https://angular.io/api/common/Location#example